# dynamic button inside dynamic literal control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add dynamic literal control and dynamic  button.

so I try like this:

```
            Literal lit = new Literal();        
            lit.Text = lit.Text + theRow["CaseExampleDescription"].ToString() + "\n\n";
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.ID = "btn1";

            lit.Controls.Add(btn);
```

but there is error -System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal' does not allow child controls.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **use a container** that would hold your `child controls (like button, literal, etc.),` thus it needs to **implement WebControl Class.**

**Literal** is not deriving from system.Web.UI.WebControls namespace. Thus can not have collection of controls.

Basically you need to use a server control as the base class that defines the methods, properties and events common to all controls in the System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace.

**How to do your task ?**

Read the following MSDN article - [How to: Add Controls to an ASP.NET Web Page Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1)

Answer (score 0):

As [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_literal.asp) points out, a literal control is nothing more than a way to display text on a page.  As such it does not support child controls.  The reason it has the controls collection is because it inherits from the system.web.ui.control.

What you are going to want to use something that does support child controls such as the asp.net [panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel).

Comment: This is Ajax function. I'm new one for Ajax.  So I want to create some dynamic controls and assign it. I try like this.. How can I return PlaceHolder???

[WebMethod]
        public static string loadCommCaseExample()
        {
           
    PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1 = new PlaceHolder();
   Label myLabel = new Label();
   myLabel.Text = "Label1";
   myLabel.ID = "Label2";
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myLabel);
  
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));


     return PlaceHolder1.ToString();
        } But This is not working....